# How to reset default permissions after the result of running the chown command

Tags: command-line, permission

I ran this line in Terminal:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

Now I want to reverse it to the default permissions. How do I do that?

(I think the default owner is system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default /usr/local is owned by root and the directories under that don't exist so there could be odd users under that, if so the restore as per [patrix's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/268059/237) otherwise

The most usual setup in Unix/Linux is to have them all owned by root. So

```
sudo chown -R root /usr/local
```

There is no such user as system by default,

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to do this. Easiest approach would to to restore the `/usr/local` hierarchy from your most recent backup (and manually reapply all changes/installs made later).